# Understanding $k[Hom(x,y]$ for a category

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I am studying representation theory of categories, and I am getting stuck on the following definition given in Sam & Snowden’s paper on Noetherian Categories.

> Define a representation $P_x$ of $C$ By $P_x(y)=k[Hom(x,y)]$, i.e. $P_x(y)$ is the free left $k$-module with basis Hom(x,y).

Now, I understand the concept of this definition, but in practice it does not make sense to me for any general small category. For instance, if we consider the poset category $C$ with Ob$(C)=\mathbb{N}$ and Mor$(C)=\{n\to m \text{ if } n\leq m\}$. Then say we look at $P_1(2)=k[Hom(1,2)]=k[1\to 2]$. What does this actually look like? $[1\to 2]$ should become a free abelian group, but I do not see or understand how.

Comment: Every morphism $\alpha: x \to y$ gives a basis element.  So, treat the morphisms as formal basis "vectors" and that's all there is to it (the addition and scalar mult are also formal).

Comment: Okay thank you I will remove the second question.

Comment: Possibly a source of confusion is due to writing $1\to 2$ for the single arrow from $1$ to $2$. A more concrete rendition of the homset may help. Define $\mathsf{Hom}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\{(x,y)\},&x\leq y\\\varnothing,&x\not\leq y\end{cases}$. $k[\mathsf{Hom}(1,2)]=k[\{(1,2)\}]$ which is the free $k$-module generated from one generator (in this case the generator is labeled $(1,2)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not $[1 \to 2]$ which is an abelian group, it's $k[1 \to 2]$. By definition, $k[\hom(x,y)]$ is the set of formal linear combinations of elements of $\hom(x,y)$ with coefficients in $k$. In other words, an element of $k[\hom(x,y)]$ is (by definition) an expression of the type:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i$$
where $\lambda_i \in k$ and $f_i \in \hom(x,y)$. Then algebra in $k[\hom(x,y)]$ is done by manipulating these expressions, adding and multiplying by scalars term-wise. In yet other words, $P_x(y)$ is a free $k$-module, with a basis given by the set $\hom(x,y)$.

It does not matter that $\hom(x,y)$ is a set of morphisms of some categories. You are not really adding functions, you are adding expressions. If for example $1 \to 2$ is a morphism of your poset category $C$, then $(1 \to 2) + (1 \to 2)$ is simply the *expression* $2 \cdot (1 \to 2)$, nothing else.

Comment: Free $k$-module can refer to two functors, either $k\otimes_{\mathbb Z} - : \mathsf{Ab} \to k\mathrm{-Mod}$ or its composition with the free abelian group functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathsf{Ab}$. That might have been the source of confusion for the OP.

Comment: This does clarify things a bit, but I’m still getting tripped up when you write something like $2\cdot (1\to 2)$. Am I supposed to be able to interpret what that means? Or is it just some new “expression” in some module?

Comment: @jgcello It's just an expression, it doesn't really mean anything. For example I could consider the free $k$-module on the set $S = \{\text{apple}, \text{orange}\}$, in which I can do the addition $\text{apple} + \text{orange}$. But it doesn't really "mean" anything other than "it's the sum in the free $k$-module on the set $S$".

Comment: @jgcello That's a bit like asking what the elements of a group algebra "mean".